# How to select parent dropdown selected value

Tags: jquery, razor, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdown in a for loop. I also have a download pdf button in this loop. I want to be able to click on this download pdf button and then in javascript select the selected value in the dropdown which then will eventually run a function and find the correct pfd location related to the selected value.

EDIT:

```
 <table>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>
        @Html.DropDownList("Dropdown", Model.Dropdowns[i], new { id = Model.Industry[i].Id, @class = "dropdown"})
     </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td></td>
       <td>
          <a href="#" class="DownloadPDF"> Download PDF</a>                                                   
       </td>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {

   $(".DownloadPDF").click(
        function () {
            var selected = $(this).parent().find(".dropdown option:selected").val();
            alert(selected);
        }
    );
});
```

this code returns only an alert saying undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to subscribe to the `change` event of your dropdown:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('select.dropdown').change(function() {
       var $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
       var $btn = $tr.next().find('a.DownloadPDF');
       $btn.attr('href', 'mydownloadhandler?pdf' + $(this).find('option:selected').val()); 
    });
});
```

Code: http://jsfiddle.net/b4Dxv/1/

Anyway, if we will start from button:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $(".DownloadPDF").click(function () {
            var selected = $(this).closest('tr').prev().find(".dropdown option:selected").val();
            alert(selected);
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: I still get undefined error, i will give your first example a go

Comment: I set wrong atribute `src` instead of `href`. I've added working sample

Answer (score 0):

Maybe without the parent:

```
var selected = $(".dropdown option:selected", $(this).parent()).val();
```

Comment: This does work, however it selects the value of the first drop down. i want the value of the drop down above the button.

Comment: for example there could be three drop downs and three buttons because this is in a loop

Comment: I added $(this).parent() as base for the select. Maybe you need $(this).parent().parent().

Answer (score 0):

I take it the dropdown and the link are in different table cells, but in the same row?

What you're doing here only checks the parent of the link. The parent of the link is a `td` element. What you need to find is the parent `tr` element. Try this:

```
var selected = $(this).closest('tr').find(".dropdown option:selected").val();
```